# How do I set up proxy for production react application?

Tags: reactjs, proxy

I am developing a React application which consumes a REST API running on another server. Now, in development, I am using the proxy by adding the proxy field in *package.json*.

I am wondering how I can configure a proxy for the production application so that my REST request can be routed to the other server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The proxy variable in your package.js file is only being used in development. I assume you are using create-react-app, [here is the doc](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development).

The way I routed all the API requests in my react app is by proxying all the requests through Nginx. Of course, it really depends on wich web server you are using.

Considering you are making all the requests to an /API endpoint you can proxy all the requests like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    add_header   Cache-Control public;
    expires      1d;
}

location /api {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_pass http://yourapiserver:port/;
}
```